# Обеспечение слабой связности элементов

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, архитектура

Здравствуйте, есть ряд классов: класс `server` и класс `connection` ничего не знают о классе `database`, о нем знает только `application`(главный класс):

```
class database {};

class server {
     void createnewconnection() {
         c.push_back(new connection());
     }
     void listen() {
          while(true) { 
              accept();              //слушаем входящие соединения
              createnewconnection(); //создаем новое подключение в другом потоке
          }
     }
     std::vector<connection> c;
};
class connection {
     connection() {
         //и тут внутри соединения принимаем данные
         switch() {
             case "get" : //взять из базы данных
             case "put" : //положить в базу данных
         }
     }
};

class application{
    application() {
        serv = new server();
        serv->listen();
    }
    server* serv;
    database* db;
};
```

В общем сервер слушает входящие соединения и делает поток на соединение(допустим), а внутри соединения в зависимости от полученных данных, мы либо берем из базы что-то, либо кладем... Так вот как реализовать грамотно чтобы не ломать тот факт, что `connect` и `server` ничего не знают о `database`, но внутри connect все же к базе данных обращаться?

Comment: какая ответственность у **connection**?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, ну в нем происходит прием/отправка сообщений к серверу и от сервера, и в ней же запрос к базе данных

Comment: для этого ему база не нужна. значит должен быть другой(ие) объект(ы), которые обрабатывают полученные сообщения и генерируют сообщения для отправки.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, а можете примерно чиркануть как?

Comment: я не достаточно хорошо владею си++ и я не знаю что именно вы хотите сделать. что делает ваша программа?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, да вот есть некая фабрика, допустим, которая генерирует объекты, внутри которых используются классы, о которых фабрика не знает ничего, вот как сделать красиво чтоб все работало не давая знать фабрике о этих классах? 
хотя не знаю как нормально описать...

Comment: это описание решения, а не задачи.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, ладно тогда